# How to create new directory in target folder with Maven

Tags: java, maven, dependencies

I am writing a library which will create a report based on the test results (imagine something like Surefire). And my problem is, I am able to create a folder in `target/` directory to hold the report and also copy there necessary files but I can do that only when I build the library project itself.

I would like to  achieve same behavior like a Surefire plugin has, that means if I put dependency for my library to some project, let's say `myProject`, then I will get something like `myProject/target/myLibrary` after the build.

btw, this is what I currently have

```
<plugin>
     <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
     <artifactId>maven-antrun-plugin</artifactId>
     <version>1.7</version>
         <executions>
             <execution>
                <phase>generate-test-sources</phase>
                <configuration>
                    <tasks>
                        <echo message="Creating folder for the lib..." />
                        <mkdir dir="${report.folder}" />
                        <echo message="Copying Twitter Bootstrap libraries to the ${report.folder}" />
                        <copy todir="${report.folder}">
                                <fileset dir="src/main/resources/bootstrap">
                                    <include name="**/**" />
                                </fileset>
                            </copy>
                        </tasks>
                    </configuration>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>run</goal>
                    </goals>
                </execution>
            </executions>
        </plugin>
```

And also bonus question, is there a variable for `src/main/resources`?

Comment: Have you looked at the code for the [Surefire plugin](http://maven.apache.org/surefire/maven-surefire-plugin/source-repository.html)?

Comment: I did but I haven't found anything helpful

Comment: I think the term 'library' is confusing here, since you can't execute a library, but it is *used* by something. How do you want to execute this piece of code? As an executable jar? How do you run it right now?

Comment: It's going to be an extension for Arquillian testing framework. There is SPI which is similar to the CDI so code is executed by listening to events from that SPI. So there is an event fired on a container startup and I would like to copy those files during this event

Comment: So if you include dependency to my extension and run the tests, code will be executed automatically

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ok, so I found the solution which is using the `getResourceAsStream()` method.

```
String classpathName = "/bootstrap/" + "css" + "/" + file;
InputStream inputStream = SetupReportDirectory.class.getResourceAsStream(classpathName);
String path = "target/myLibrary/bootstrap";
FileOutputStream outputStream = new FileOutputStream(path);
IOUtils.copy(inputStream, outputStream);
```

Answer (score 0):

In your library, simply check if the `target` directory (and/or whatever sub-directory you're interested in) exists. If it doesn't just use `File.mkdirs(...)` and create it. That's what the `maven-surefire-plugin` is doing.

Comment: Yes, that works, but I also need to copy files there. And if I do `FileUtils.copyDirectoryToDirectory(new File("src/main/resources/bootstrap"), new File("target/myLibrary")` then I will get `FileNotFoundException` - bootstrap doesn't exist in the project which is using the library

Comment: Well, obviously, you first have to check if the `target` directory exists and create it, if it doesn't. Then you can perform the copying using the respective method from the `FileUtils` class. This should do the trick.

Comment: Yes, but this directory certainly exists because I execute `new File("target/myLibrary").mkdir();` command before this one. So I guess the problem is that `src/main/resources/bootstrap` is not on the classpath at the moment.